# How was the official Monero website hacked to deliver malware at the end of 2019?

Tags: security, build, history, attack

According to [arstechnica](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2019/11/official-monero-website-is-hacked-to-deliver-currency-stealing-malware/), on November 18th 2019 the official Monero website was hacked to deliver compromised binaries. Is any information available on how this attack occurred? Was it the website that was compromised (as the link suggests), or was it the Monero build server?

Comment: This is still unknown until a post mortem is released.

Answer (score 3):

It was the server hosting the binaries that was compromised during this attack. Luckily signed files with the genuine binary hashes were available on other sources and servers, so the attack was noticed fairly quickly. Here is the announcement on r/monero relating to the compromise: https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/dyfozs/security_warning_cli_binaries_available_on/ .

Additionally security researcher SerHack published a postmortem on the binaries and the hack itself that goes into some more detail: https://serhack.me/articles/cli-binaries-compromised-monero-analysis/ .